# Putting value from an array in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a table view in which i want to put row names from my array's object.

I have declared an array

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

in my tableView how can I put value from this array.I didn't find ObjectAtIndex method, so I am doing this

```
myLabel.text= String(format: "%@",array [ indexPath.row])
```

Comment: `let myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; let text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"`. You should read [The Swift Programming Guide: Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285), which covers String Interpolation.

Comment: when I can use let and var in case of Array? should I use let for NSArray and var for NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way.

```
myLabel.text= String(stringInterpolationSegment: myArray[indexPath.row]!)
```

Comment: yes both way are correct . but can you tell me difference between both methods?

Comment: with "\ (yourValue)" usage you can cast your any value to string but if it is complex variables, appending or dynamically created , it is better using  stringInterpolationSegment method

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using **string interpolation**:

```
myLabel.text = "\(array[indexPath.row])"
```

If you want to know more, consult the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)

Comment: Its working for me. Is ObjectAtIndex removed in Swift?

Comment: `objectAtIndex` is a method of `NSArray`, in swift that's been replaced by the subscript operator `[]`. However the swift array and `NSString` are compatible and interchangeable, you can just cast an array into `NSString` to have access to all its properties and methods: `let nsArray = array as NSArray`

Answer (score 1):

Your `myArray` is swift `Array` of type `[Int]` and it is not `NSArray`, swift array doesn't have property `ObjectAtIndex` so you can access element from swift array with index this way:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
myLabel.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"
```

And `myArray[indexPath.row]` will return Int because `myArray` type is `[Int]`.

If you want to assign text to `myLabel` then you have to convert that to `String` from `Int` and you can do that by string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes there. First you have declared myArray not array. Second when using integers you have to use %d. Try like this:

```
let myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

myLabel.text = String(format: "%d", myArray[indexPath.row])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this also:

```
myLabel.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(" %.02f %.02f %.02f", r, g, b)
```